# System.IO.Ports.SerialPort stops sending after 8KB

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have this code, which sends data through the serial port with a simple header with the data length.

```
public void WriteToPort(string message)
{
    byte[] messageBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
    int length = messageBytes.Length;

    byte b0 = (byte)((length >> 24) & 0xFF);
    byte b1 = (byte)((length >> 16) & 0xFF);
    byte b2 = (byte)((length >> 8) & 0xFF);
    byte b3 = (byte)((length >> 0) & 0xFF);

    List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>() { b0, b1, b2, b3};
    bytes.AddRange(messageBytes);

    if (serialPort != null && !serialPort.IsOpen)
    {
        serialPort.Open();
    }

    serialPort.Write(bytes.ToArray(), 0, bytes.Count);
}
```

I use this code to send data from a Desktop application to a device, connected to the serial port.

This code was working flawlessly, sending data to my device without an issue. The problem started when we integrated some other applications on the device, which made it significantly slower. This was expected and it does not affect the communication at all.

After that, my desktop application appears to send all the data, but the device only receives exactly 8KB of data. We tried sending the same data using RealTerm and it worked, so the problem is probably on this piece of code.

Do you have any idea why this is happening?

EDIT: Sorry, I forgot to mention that I already tried sending the data in small chunks and it did not work.

Comment: I imagine that you're hitting some sort of buffer limit. Why not loop, sending 2048 bytes (for instance) at a time until the message is sent?

Comment: I already tried that (and updated the question) and it did not work, unfortunately.

Comment: The only Red Flag in this snippet is the Open() call.  A program that constantly closes and re-opens a port is likely to fail on the Open() call.  There's a worker thread that needs to exit after the Close() call.  That takes time, the more heavily the machine is loaded the longer that takes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    public void WriteToPort(string message)
    {
        // Throw exception if serialPort is not initialised.
        // Old code would have thrown from serialPort.Write
        if (serialPort == null) throw new InvalidOperationException();

        // Convert message to bytes
        byte[] messageBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);
        // Convert message length to bytes
        byte[] lengthBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(messageBytes.Length);

        // Convert message length bytes to big endian if needed
        if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) Array.Reverse(lengthBytes);

        // Open serial port if needed
        if (!serialPort.IsOpen) serialPort.Open();

        // Write length
        serialPort.Write(lengthBytes, 0, lengthBytes.Length);
        // Write message
        serialPort.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
    }
```

Also things to check:

- Are you sure the device expects a **BIG ENDIAN** encoded **INT** prefix to the data with the number of bytes **excluding the length itself**?
- Are you sure you have the serial port configured with the correct flow control and handshaking options?
- Are you sure the UTF8 encoding is correct for the device?